# Error "Unpublished posts must be posted to a page as the page itself" when trying to upload unpublished image post to a page's group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a FB page under my account and I created a group with that page, and I'm trying to post an unpublished post of image to the group in order to get the postId of the image so I can post multiple images in the same post using these image postIds, when I do that with my regular FB account it works perfectly fine, but when I try to upload an unpublished post of image to the group with my page I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) Unpublished posts must be posted to a page as the page itself.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200
    }
}
```

I have seen these two posts having the same problems and solving it:

[(OAuthException - #200) (#200) Unpublished posts must be posted to a page as the page itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368099/oauthexception-200-200-unpublished-posts-must-be-posted-to-a-page-as-the)

[Posting to a Facebook Page as the Page (not a person)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239482/posting-to-a-facebook-page-as-the-page-not-a-person)

The conclusion of the posts is that there are a few types of access tokens one for the main account and one for the page which I already knew because I'm already using the `/me/accounts` (like in the second link) to get the page's access token which I use it to publish text posts to the group as the page, which works great, but for some reason posting an unpublished post of image to my page's group doesn't work, here's the full HTTP request I'm trying to do which causes the above error response:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{group-id}/photos?access_token={page-access-token}

Form-data body: url: {jpg-url}, published: false
```

Comment: `url` and `published` should be passed as query string parameters?

Comment: @ArpitJain Not query, but as form-data, it works like this for the FB account's access token but not for the FB page access token..

Comment: In the doc, I see them as query parameters.

Comment: @ArpitJain Just tried as query params I get the same error

Comment: Are you basically trying to create an unpublish post? I will try and reproduce the error.

Comment: @ArpitJain Yes, I have an FB page that I created with my regular account, with that FB page I have created a FB group, I am trying to post multiple unpublished images one by one to that group with that endpoint so I'll get in the response the postId, after that I can use multiple such postIds to post a published=true post which will cause all the unpublished images to be combined to one post, I couldn't find a better way to post multiple images in the same post, BTW if you know of a method I'd love to hear about it :)